# How to kill a process by its pid in linux

Tags: linux, bash, process, command, kill

I'm new in linux and I'm building a program that receives the name of a process, gets its PID (i have no problem with that part) and then pass the PID to the kill command but its not working. It goes something like this:

```
read -p "Process to kill: " proceso
proid= pidof $proceso
echo "$proid"
kill $proid
```

Can someone tell me why it isn't killing it ? I know that there are some other ways to do it, even with the PID, but none of them seems to work for me. I believe it's some kind of problem with the Bash language (which I just started learning).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of this:

> ```
> proid= pidof $proceso
> ```

You probably meant this:

```
proid=$(pidof $proceso)
```

Even so,
the program might not get killed.
By default, `kill PID` sends the `TERM` signal to the specified process,
giving it a chance to shut down in an orderly manner,
for example clean up resources it's using.
The strongest signal to send a process to kill without graceful cleanup is `KILL`, using `kill -KILL PID` or `kill -9 PID`.

---

> I believe it's some kind of problem with the bash language (which I just started learning).

The original line you posted, `proid= pidof $proceso` should raise an error,
and Bash would print an error message about it.
Debugging problems starts by reading and understanding the error messages the software is trying to tell you.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I tried all of your solutions but the problem was right there at what you pointed. Didn't know I had to put all that expression beetween ()'s and with $ at the beginning. I'll be more concerned about it now, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

use the following command to display the port and PID of the process:

```
sudo netstat -plten
```

AND THEN

```
kill -9 PID
```

Here is an example to kill a process running on port 8283 and has PID=25334

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**kill** expects you to tell it **how to kill*, so there must be 64 different ways to kill your process :) They have names and numbers. The most lethal is `-9`. Some interesting ones include:

- SIGKILL - The SIGKILL (also `-9`) signal forces the process to stop executing immediately. The program cannot ignore this signal. This process does not get to clean-up either.
- SIGHUP - The SIGHUP signal disconnects a process from the parent process. This an also be used to restart processes. For example, "killall -SIGUP compiz" will restart Compiz. This is useful for daemons with memory leaks.
- SIGINT - This signal is the same as pressing ctrl-c. On some systems, "delete" + "break" sends the same signal to the process. The process is interrupted and stopped. However, the process can ignore this signal.
- SIGQUIT - This is like SIGINT with the ability to make the process produce a core dump.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the SIGKILL flag with the kill statement. 
`kill -9 [pid]`
If you don't the operating system will choose to kill the process at its convenience, SIGKILL (-9) will tell the os to kill the process NOW without ignoring the command until later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
kill -9 
It will kill any process with PID given in brackets

Answer (score 0):

Try "kill -9 $proid" or "kill -SIGKILL $proid" commands. If you want more information, [click](http://www.linux.org/threads/kill-commands-and-signals.4423/).

Comment: SIGKILL should only be used as a last resort: it prevents the process from gracefully shutting down.  For more details, see [When should I not kill -9 a process?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have there, it looks like you aren't getting the actual PID in your `proid` variable. If you want to capture the output of `pidof`, you will need to enclose that command in backtics for the old form of [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) ...

```
proid=`pidof $proceso`
```

... or like so for the new form of command substitution.

```
proid=$(pidof $proceso)
```

Comment: I realized that after you guys told me haha thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, only wanting to run monitor (Video surveillance) for several hours a day.
Wrote two sh scripts;

cat startmotion.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
motion -c /home/username/.config/motion/motion.conf
```

And the second;
cat killmotion.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
OA=$(cat /var/run/motion/motion.pid)
kill -9 $OA
```

These were called from crontab at the scheduled time

```
ctontab -e
0 15 * * * /home/username/startmotion.sh
0 17 * * * /home/username/killmotion.sh
```

Very simple, but that's all I needed.